# Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type (Int, Int, Int)

Tags: haskell

i have a dynamic txt file example (1,1,1), im trying to read them from file
to pass them to problem function.

function `problem :: Int->Int->Int->[Int]`

```
   args <- getArgs
   contents <- readFile (head args)
   let value = read contents::(Int,Int,Int)

   //print(show(problem 1 1 1))
   print(show(problem value))
```

> Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
> with actual type ‘(Int, Int, Int)’

Comment: Well, `value` is a tuple, not 3 separate `Int` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the three `Int` values in order to pass them individually to `problem`.

```
let (a, b, c) = read contents :: (Int, Int, Int)
print (show (problem a b c))
```

Conversely, you could define an `uncurry3` function to adapt `problem` to work with a tuple.

```
uncurry3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> ((a, b, c) -> d)
uncurry3 f = \(x,y,z) -> f x y z

print (show ((uncurry3 problem) value))
```